# Erro 'VALUES' (T_STRING) no php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou com um erro nas variáveis ao tentar chamar pelo banco de dados e aparece a seguinte mensagem :

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'VALUES' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\formcadastro\conexao2.php on line 24**

Esta nesta linha o erro :

```
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO cadastro ('idCad', 'Nome', 'Email', 'Senha', 'Confirmar', 'Telefone', 'Celular', 'Nascimento', 'Sexo', 'Bairro', 'Cidade', 'Estado')" 
VALUES ('$idCad', '$nome', '$email', '$senha', '$confirmar', '$telefone', '$celular', '$nascimento', '$sexo', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$estado');
```

Como posso arrumar ?

Comment: Aconselho aprender interpretar as mensagens de erro. Caso contrário vai levar muito tempo para fazer qualquer coisa útil, porque além de cometer erros muito básicos, não tem ideia do que está acontecendo. Se tiver que fazer uma pergunta pra alguém toda hora que se deparar com u merro, vai levar horas para fazer algo que alguém faz em minutos. E continua tendo um sério problema de segurança.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fechando a string com " antes da palavra VALUES.

Teste:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cadastro ('idCad', 'Nome', 'Email', 'Senha', 'Confirmar', 'Telefone', 'Celular', 'Nascimento', 'Sexo', 'Bairro', 'Cidade', 'Estado') VALUES ('$idCad', '$nome', '$email', '$senha', '$confirmar', '$telefone', '$celular', '$nascimento', '$sexo', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$estado')";
```

Comment: Funcionou,obrigado.